# ui-router will not redirect when authentication is required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

A redirect to the login page should happen if a user has not authenticated yet. `$state.go("login");` should accomplish this, but it doesn't do anything.

```
// in app.js

$stateProvider
.state('login', {
    template: 'login.html'
    url: '/login',
    controller: 'AuthenticationCtrl',
})
.state('special', {
    resolve: { loginRequired: checkAuthenticated },
    template: 'special.html',
    url: '/special', 
    controller: 'SpecialCtrl',
})

var checkAuthenticated = function($state, AuthenticationService, $q, $timeout) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
        deferred.resolve();
    } else {
        deferred.reject();
        alert('You are being redirected to login page');
        $state.go("login");    // redirect to login page -- but this does nothing.
    }
}
```

Here, if a user has not authenticated and tries to access a route that requires authentication, I see my alert pop up. But nothing happens afterwards; `ui-router` doesn't redirect to my login page.

I also tried out `$location.path('/login')` instead of `$state.go("login")`, but this also does not do anything.

I checked the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) it says for `go()`:

```
String Absolute State Name or Relative State Path
```

Which I have, so I must be missing something that's causing this problem, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I've experienced issues with state go in conjunction with an alert, I solved this by using a timeout set to 100ms or so, eg: delay your state.go and perhaps this will solve your issue.

Comment: @ErikSvedin Thanks, using a `$timeout` works. If you make an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced issues with state go in conjunction with an alert, I solved this by using a `$timeout` set to 100ms or so, eg: delay your state.go and hopefully this will solve your issue.